# Configure Redelivery for a file when Exception occures in camel route

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel

I have a pretty easy route where I pickup files from a directory and send it to a bean:

`from("file:/mydir?delete=true").bean(MyProcessor.class);`

It can happen that an exception occures in MyProcessor.class and so I want to delay the processing of that file again. How can I setup a redelivery for that as I tried already different things with

`onException().redeliveryDelay(10000);`

but it didn't work and right after the exception the same file gets processed again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do `onException()` before Processing?

Example:

```
errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler()
        .maximumRedeliveries(2)
        .redeliveryDelay(5000)
        .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN));

// exception handler for specific exceptions
onException(IOException.class).maximumRedeliveries(1).redeliveryDelay(5000);

//only the failed record send write to error folder
onException(CsvRecordException.class)
        .to("file:/app/dev/dataland/error");

onCompletion()
        .log("global thread: ${threadName}")
        .to("file:/app/dev/dataland/archive");

from("file:/path?noop=true?delay=3000")
        .startupOrder(1)
        .log("start to process file: ${header.CamelFileName}")
        .bean(CsvFilePreLoadChecker.class, "validateMetaData")
        .end()
        .log("Done processing file: ${header.CamelFileName}");
```

Answer (score 0):

When an error occurs in `MyProcessor.class` the route processing is failed and therefore the file consumer **does not delete the file**.

Since the route processing is completed, the **file consumer simply reads the (still present) file again**.

If you want to move files with processing errors out of your way, you can use the `moveFailed` option of the [file consumer](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.12.x/file-component.html). You would then have to move them back periodically to retry.

If you want to decouple file reading and `MyProcessor.class` you need to split the route into 2 routes. One that reads read the files and sends its messages to a queue or similar. The other consumes that queue and processes the messages.